# Image float to the right and not have text or other elements wrap on the left

Tags: html, css

I want the logo below to align with the right of the page. I've tried adding `float:right`, but that causes the horizontal line to wrap around on the left. I don't want anything else occupying the vertical space.

[image: Screenshot]

Here is my HTML

```
<header >
   <div>
      <img  style="margin-right:40px; padding-bottom:20px" src="./AddFiles/bamboo_logo.png" height="50">
      <br>
      <hr>
   </div>
</header>
```

Comment: This is just what is `float` designed for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try adding text align to the containing `div`: ([**Working jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/y2n0r3x2/))

```
<header>
   <div style="text-align:right;"> <!-- add this css, images are by default inline -->
      <img style="margin-right:40px; padding-bottom:20px" src="./AddFiles/bamboo_logo.png" height="50">
      <br>
      <hr>
   </div>
</header>
```